# Exit program for fingerprint after 15 seconds of no input on fingerprintsensor PYTHON

Tags: python, time, fingerprint

:) I have a problem I can't solve myself( I tried a lot with `time.time()` but I never solved my problem). 
I would like my program to exit and stop waiting for finger if 15 seconds passed. I would be really happy and grateful if someone knows how to do it in python!
Thank you very much! Ask me if there are any questions! The code is down below!

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/scripts')
import subprocess
import lcddriver
from time import *


lcd = lcddriver.lcd()
lcd.lcd_clear()

import hashlib
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint


## Tries to initialize the sensor
try:
f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
    raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
lcd.lcd_display_string('Initialization failed!', 2)
print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ 
str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to search the finger and calculate hash
try:
 f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
    raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

except Exception as e:
lcd.lcd_display_string('Initialization failed!', 2)
print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
exit(1)

## Gets some sensor information
print('Currently used templates: ' + str(f.getTemplateCount()) +'/'+ 
str(f.getStorageCapacity()))

## Tries to search the finger and calculate hash
try:
lcd.lcd_display_string(' Waiting for finger', 2)

## Wait that finger is read
while ( f.readImage() == False ):
    pass

## Converts read image to characteristics and stores it in charbuffer 1
f.convertImage(0x01)

## Searchs template
result = f.searchTemplate()

positionNumber = result[0]
accuracyScore = result[1]
 if ( positionNumber == -1 ):

    os.system('python access_denied.py')
    exit(0)
 else:
    lcd.lcd_clear()
    lcd.lcd_display_string("  Finger accepted!", 2)
    sleep(1.5)
    lcd.lcd_clear()
    os.system('python keypad.py')
```

Comment: what's you tried so far with `time.time()`

Comment: I tried implementing ´start = time.time()´ when while loop starts and ´end = time.time() ´ - start asking in a loop if end - start < 15. The problem is that I don't know how to make a comparison with that time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
timeout = time.time() + 15 # 15s from now
while True:
   # do stuff
    end_time = time.time()
    if end_time > timeout or f.readImage():
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(0.25) # sleep to reduce CPU usage
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! What do you mean with "do stuff"?

Comment: ah, you can do something before check the finger print in each loop. Just ignore if you don't need it

Comment: Perfect - it works! You are awesome man!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed starting a thread to keep the count of time and close the program after set time ? When a fingerprint is read the the program shuts down the thread before the thread shuts down the program.
I personally don't have much experience with multithreading beiond general knowledge so i don't exactly know how to apply this but this showld help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Thank you for helping! I will definately read myself through multithreading although I got the solution now!:)